# Ruby twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am just started learning Ruby rails and immediately facing problem.

I am using Windows 8.1, Ruby 2.2.3, Rails 4.2.5.
Problem is I installed twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, like this:

```
   gem install twitter-bootstrap-rails
```

, and it said me everything have gone well, no problems. But when I type

```
   bundle show twitter-bootstrap-rails
```

it says me there is no such gem. And for that reason I think I cant use rails generator, bootstrap is not in generators list:

```
   rails g --help
```

I am completely new in Ruby. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you making use of any ruby versioning tools like rbenv or rvm? If not I highly recommend using that to overcome such issues

Comment: @bpn Thank you! But honestly I cant manage installing even one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you need to do is add the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem to your `Gemfile`, and run `bundle install`.

Although you installed the gem using `gem install`, `bundler` doesn't know that because it's not present in your Gemfile.

Once you add the gem to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`, `bundle show` should display the path of the installed gem. Your generators should work as well!